# Integral submanifolds of an involutive manifold over $M$ posess an unique structure of smooth submanifold of $M$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

Consider a smooth manifold $M$, an involutive distribution $D$ over $M$, and $N\subset M$. We need to prove that if $N$ admits a structure of integral submanifold of $D$, then $N$ admits an unique structure of smooth manifold of $M$.

I'm sure that the Global Frobenius Theorem has to be used somewhere, because we can rewrite it as *"any involutive distribution has asociated one and only one foliation"*, which is similar to what I want to achieve. The Local Frobenius Theorem also assures us that $D$ has to be integrable, but I don't know if this is of any help.

Could anyone please help me out? All of these concepts are very new to me, so any lead of what to do would be helpful (wouldn't like to have the full answer, just a hint).

Comment: Can you recall what is an integral submanifold?

Comment: $N$ is an integral submanifold of $D$ if for all $p\in N$, $T_pN= D(p)$.

Comment: $N$ is a submanifold to start with?

Comment: Huh, it is. $N$ has to be a smooth submanifold of $M$. So the important bit about this exercise is to see that the structure is unique?

Comment: I guess I am a bit confused. An embedded submanifold $N$ of $M$ always has an unique smooth structure (so that it is an embedded submanifold of $M$) (see Lee's Theorem 5.31). It has nothing to do with the distribution.

Comment: But we don't know right away if $N$ is embedded. It is said for any submanifold.

Comment: What is your definition of a submanifold?

Comment: $N$ is a submanifold of $M$ if $i:N\hookrightarrow M$ is an inmersion. It is embedded if its topology is induced by $M$.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. It uses a result that says the following:

> **Theorem:** Let $F:M\to N$ a smooth function between two smooth manifolds. If we consider $P$ an integral submanifold of $D$ such that $F(M)\subset P$, then $F_0:M\to P$ is smooth.

The thing is to prove that if we consider two smooth structures, prove that they are the same. If we consider $N_1$ and $N_2$ the set $N$ with two structures of submanifold, we can see that $Id_N:N_1\to N_2$ is a diffeomorphism thanks to the previous theorem.

Considering $i_1:N_1\to M$, we have that $i_1(N_1)\subset N_2$ ,and so $(i_1)_0 = Id_N:N_1\to N_2$ is smooth, and by considering $i_2:N_2\to M$, then $i_2(N_2)\subset N_1$, and then $(i_2)_0=(Id_N)^{-1}:N_2\to N_1$ is smooth.

It was a similar prove to check that embedded submanifolds have an unique structure, since a similar theorem to the one writen above was used. I don't know if there are something specific I need to address.